# Compile multiple scss files in same folder to multiple file in one script

Tags: css, node.js, json, sass, npm-scripts

I'm trying to define in the package.json file, one script that will compile multiple scss files into files with the same name in the same folder, possible?

I write in TS/JS.

The current situation:

```
/src
    /style/
           a.scss
           b.scss
```

I tried this  script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {"build-sass": "sass src/style/*.scss ./src/style/*.css"}
```

The desired result:

```
/src
    /style/
           a.scss
           a.css
           a.map
           b.scss
           b.css
           b.map
```

Many thanks in advance to all the helpers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on the Sass website.
[image: The solution]

For all the files in all subfolders and saved in the same folder with the same names, I wrote this
"scripts": {"dev-sass": "sass --watch ./:./"}

Comment: Please don't include picture but copy the text directly, so people can copy paste the content and the given commands